# Get user info like name, email Id etc from authentication token in Node.JS Backend Mobile Service

Tags: node.js, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to construct this following solution - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2d527121-42dd-4ed3-a68f-a70ad0a36c0d/get-user-info-like-name-email-id-etc-from-authentication-token-in-net-backend-mobile-service?forum=azuremobile&prof=required

This is based on C# solution. Since we are new on this Azure Mobile App, we  are taking the approach of using Node.JS instead as per Quick Start solution/Xamarin doco.

How do we turn this into node.JS backend then?

Thanks

Comment: are you using Mobile services or Mobile Apps?

Comment: On the Azure, it's located under Web+Mobile > Mobile App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/) feature for this.

Retrieving the email from the auth token also depends on the authentication source. For example, if you are using MSA, the email is not part of the claim. Please refer my blog post on how to add the email field in the claim in case of MSA.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2016/04/01/azure-web-apps-how-to-retrieve-user-email-in-the-claim-when-using-microsoft-account-as-a-provider-in-easy-auth/

Comment: Actually I have done that part to enable Authentication/authorisation in azure mobile app that we have and integrate with Xamarin.forms application. We got authentication/authorisation working. The issue is how to get more detail of the authenticated user ie their name, email , etc etc But since our mobile app backend is running on Node.Js NOT .Net and the sample solution running on C# (see above).

Comment: I understood that, as I said you will have to enable the fields **wl.basic** & **wl.emails** to have this as part of the claim. I shared my blog to show how to do it via the UI. You can do it via code too.

Comment: As per the above post, you need to hit the /.auth/me endpoint to retrieve claims. There is no convenience function on the client to help with this, but it should just be a simple HTTP request. If you are working on the server side, you can call req.azureMobile.user.getIdentity() to retrieve claims. There is a reference for the /.auth/me endpoint at http://www.danderson00.com/2016/09/blog-post.html

Comment: How about for Facebook/Google/Twitter stuff? As this authenticated providers doesn't have like Microsoft one ie. wl.basic and wl,emails? Do I need to go to each providers and toggle some settings then?

Comment: Other auth providers have that field provided by default.

Comment: How do we get that fields then? Is that the same thing then like Microsoft Account?

Comment: what I meant was for other auth providers the email field is by default part of the user claim and you don't have to enable additional fields. In case if it has been removed explicitly, then you will have to add the fields as in case of Microsoft Account.